# Retrieving a many to many to many relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a user that has (many to many) books and each book can have many tags. I want to retrieve one specific user's books that have at least one tag like this:

```
book1 -> tag1
      -> tag2
book2 -> tag3
      -> tag2
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You need to include some code, what have you tried? What does your models and controller method look like?

Comment: Actually, I do have establish all proper relations in my models. So, 
In Users I have:

    public function Books(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book');
    }
In Books I have:

     public function users()
     {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
     }
    
     public function tags()
      {
         return $this->hasMany('App\book');
      }
and in tags I have:

     public function book()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\book');
      }

I should finally mention that, there is also a pivot table book_user. 
I now want to make this query with eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the eager loading like:

```
$user->with(['books.tags'])->get();
```

In case you need help with setting the relationships check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: It is $user->with(['books.tags'])->get();

Comment: ... and furthermore, I can make a  $user->has('books.tags')->count(); to see if the user has any books with tags. Super.

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation for this to show up. Once I get 15points it will. Sorry man, thanks again.